# ExitProcess error in MASM using dosbox on macOS

Tags: macos, assembly, masm, dosbox

I'm new to assembly language, and I want to run an asm program on dosbox in macOS

I follow the this instruction:
[Install MASM 8086 DOSBOX(Run Microprocessors program) on MAC OSX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoJNbxbuw1k)

and here's the asm code I want to run:

```
; AddTwo.asm - adds two 32-bit integers

.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.code
main PROC
   mov eax,5
   add eax,6

   INVOKE  ExitProcess,0
main ENDP
END main
```

I assemble it on dosbox, then errors occur:

> addtwo.ASM(7): error A2105: Expected: instruction or directive

> addtwo.ASM(14): error A2105: Expected: instruction or directive

[dosbox screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGygM.png)

it seems like the exit process isn't work well, but I have no idea what's going wrong and how to fix it.

help pls!

Comment: This looks like a Windows, not a DOS program.  Where did you get it from?

Comment: I think ExitProcess is a WinAPI Windows function, not DOS.  If you want to run code like that on MacOS, you'll need WINE to run Windows binaries, not DOSBox to run DOS binaries.  And of course you'd have to assemble + link it into a Windows `.exe`.  Probably best to find a tutorial for the kind of asm you actually want to learn, perhaps native x86-64 or ARM64 asm on your Mac.

Comment: In any case, that prototype declaration looks wrong. It ought to be `ExitProcess PROTO STDCALL :DWORD`. Also, you'd have to link against kernel32.lib. But as others have noted, this would then be a Windows executable, not a DOS executable.

Comment: @fuz from the textbook "Assembly Language for x86 Processors" by Kip Irvine. Could you tell me the difference between Windows program and DOS program?

Comment: Windows uses PE executables, while DOS used the older MZ executables. But more fundamentally, the memory models and the way you interact with the OS from your code differs between the two operating systems. You have to pick one or the other, and the use a suitable toolchain and runtime environment.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. But I've tried wine to install MASM32 and it doesn't work. I think it's because macOS doesn't support 32-bit app in newer version.

Comment: Oh right, modern MacOS dropped support for obsolete 32-bit user-space, so it's possible that it's not just lack of native libraries and even WINE can't use compat mode.  If you want to write 32-bit Windows programs, you might need a VM or emulator (with Linux + WINE for MASM + Irvine32, or even actual Windows.)  Of course, you could just pick a different book instead of that quirky set of Irvine32 toy library functions.  MASM is kind of overcomplicated in some ways, with "high level" features like INVOKE that hide the asm details you're trying to learn.

Comment: @JimmyyyChen Windows and DOS programs are entirely different, starting with that DOS programs run in real mode and are subject to segmentation while Windows programs run in protected mode and are not.  Also, the API you program with (or against) differs considerably.

Answer (score 2):

From your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGygM.png), it's running MASM v5.0 and the **INVOKE** keyword was not added until MASM v6.0

[image: invoke]

Instead of **INVOKE**, try the old school code using the CALL instruction

```
push    0
call    ExitProcess
```